PKG_CONFIG missing Rust with EXIF
I am attempting to create a Rust function to parse image metadata for png, jpg, jpeg, heic, and other common formats. I was attempting to use the EXIF crate exif = "0.0.1", however I receive this error log:

Executing task: CodeLLDB: cargo

Running `cargo build --bin=rust_file_scrub --package=rust_file_scrub --message-format=json`...
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
    Updating crates.io index
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
    Blocking waiting for file lock on package cache
   Compiling exif-sys v0.1.0
   Compiling tiff v0.6.1
error: failed to run custom build command for `exif-sys v0.1.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `e:\file_scrub\rust_file_scrub\target\debug\build\exif-sys-e9172f41e2a5fece\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBEXIF_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBEXIF_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBEXIF_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_STATIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALL_DYNAMIC
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_PATH
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at C:\Users\hchap\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\exif-sys-0.1.0\build.rs:4:41:
  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "\npkg-config exited with status code 1\n> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=C:\\msys64\\usr\\lib\\pkgconfig PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1 PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1 pkg-config --libs --cflags libexif\n\nThe system library `libexif` required by crate `exif-sys` was not found.\nThe file `libexif.pc` needs to be installed and the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable must contain its parent directory.\nPKG_CONFIG_PATH contains the following:\n    - C\n    - \\msys64\\usr\\lib\\pkgconfig\n\nHINT: you may need to install a package such as libexif, libexif-dev or libexif-devel.\n"
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
Error: Cargo invocation failed.
        at t.Cargo.getCargoArtifacts (c:\Users\hchap\.vscode\extensions\vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.10.0\extension.js:1:14943)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
        at async Object.open (c:\Users\hchap\.vscode\extensions\vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.10.0\extension.js:1:13253)
Caused by: Error: exit code: 101.
        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (c:\Users\hchap\.vscode\extensions\vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.10.0\extension.js:1:16610)
        at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
        at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
        at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:303:5)
 *  The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

I have attempted to install PKG-CONFIG with msys64, such that the directory C:\msys64\mingw64\bin contains "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\pkg-config.exe"
"C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll"
"C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config.exe", and I have added this directory to path. I have also located a directory C:\msys64\usr\share\pkgconfig containing "C:\msys64\usr\share\pkgconfig\bash-completion.pc" and "C:\msys64\usr\share\pkgconfig\libmakepkg.pc", which I also added to path.
My actual rust code:
use chrono::{Date, DateTime};
use std::fs::{File, metadata};
use image::io::Reader;
use exif::{DateTime, Exif};

pub enum FileError{
    NoSuchFile,
    UnableToRead
}

pub fn path_exists(path: Str) -> bool {
    return fs::metadata(path).is_ok();
}

pub fn get_file_date(filepath: &str) -> Result<(u32, u32, u32), FileError> {
    if filepath.contains(".png") || filepath.contains(".jpg") || filepath.contains(".heic"){
        if let Ok(file) = File::open(filepath) {
            if let Ok(reader) = image::io::Reader::open(file) {
                if let Some(exif) = reader.into_exif() {
                    if let Some(datetime) = exif.get_field(exif::Tag::DateTime, false) {
                        if let Some(datetime) = datetime.value.get_decoded() {
                            if let DateTime::DateTime(dt) = datetime {
                                return Some((dt.day(), dt.month(), dt.year()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if let Ok(metadata) = metadata(filepath) {
        if let Ok(created) = metadata.created() {
            if let Ok(time) = created.duration_since(std::time::UNIX_EPOCH) {
                let datetime = chrono::NaiveDateTime::from_timestamp(time.as_secs() as i64, 0);
                return Some((datetime.day(), datetime.month(), datetime.year()));
            }
        }
    }
    return FileError::NoSuchFile;
}

And main.rs:
mod file_management;
use file_management::get_file_creation_date;

fn main() {
    let file_path: String = String::from("E:/test_directory/photos/download.jpg");
    if let Ok((year, month, day)) = get_file_date(file_path){
        println!("{file_path} was created on {day}/{month}/{year}")
    }
}

And my cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "rust_file_scrub"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4"
exif = "0.0.1"
image = "0.23"


You need to install the C libexif library (the exif Rust crate is just a wrapper for the C library).

I'd suggest using the vastly more popular https://crates.io/crates/kamadak-exif which is written in pure Rust and thus is easy to use cross-platform with cargo.

Thanks - I've found an implementation for that and managed to get it working for my needs. Do you have any recommendations for doing the same for videos?
